# How to group array of objects by date in swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, date, grouping

Need to group according to date. Response coming is in sorted format. Need to apply a filter on date to group. 
Response coming from backend:

```
[
    {
    "date": "date1"
    }, 
    {
    "date": "date1"
    },
    {
    "date": "date1"
    },
    {
    "date": "date2"
    },
    {
    "date": "date2"
    },
    {
    "date": "date3"
    }
]
```

Required:

```
[
    [
        "date": "2017-05-30T12:40:39.000Z",
        "message": [
            {
                "date_time": 2017-05-30T12: 40: 39.000Z
            }
        ]
    ],
    [
        "date": "2017-05-31T05:43:17.000Z",
        "message": [
            {
                "date_time": 2017-05-31T05: 43: 17.000Z
            },
            {
                "date_time": 2017-05-31T05: 44: 15.000Z
            },
            {
                "date_time": 2017-05-31T05: 44: 38.000Z
            }
        ]
    ]
]
```

I have checked multiple answers but wasn't able to find a good solution.

Comment: How are you grouping the objects? Based on what logic?

Comment: post your solution so far.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This is my solution to group by date(just day, month and year):

```
let groupDic = Dictionary(grouping: arr) { (pendingCamera) -> DateComponents in

    let date = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .year, .month], from: (pendingCamera.date)!)

    return date
}
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use an array extension.

```
extension Array {
  func sliced(by dateComponents: Set<Calendar.Component>, for key: KeyPath<Element, Date>) -> [Date: [Element]] {
    let initial: [Date: [Element]] = [:]
    let groupedByDateComponents = reduce(into: initial) { acc, cur in
      let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents(dateComponents, from: cur[keyPath: key])
      let date = Calendar.current.date(from: components)!
      let existing = acc[date] ?? []
      acc[date] = existing + [cur]
    }

    return groupedByDateComponents
  }
}
```

You can use it on any model property using the Swift 5 KeyPath

```
let grouped = models.sliced(by: [.year, .month, .day], for: \.createdAt)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use `flatMap` and `filter` like this to group your array to dictionary.

```
let datesArray = yourArray.flatMap { $0["date"] as? String } // return array of date
var dic = [String:[[String:Any]]]() // Your required result
datesArray.forEach {
    let dateKey = $0
    let filterArray = yourArray.filter { $0["date"] as? String == dateKey }
    dic[$0] = filterArray
}
print(dic)
```

**Note:** Make sure one thing that dictionary don't have any order so order of printing of `date` might changed.

Answer (score 8):

Thank you [ElegyD](https://gist.github.com/ElegyD/abc5dc819c9e7286452a6eb7e92fa9bb). This is worked for me.

```
extension Sequence {
    func groupSort(ascending: Bool = true, byDate dateKey: (Iterator.Element) -> Date) -> [[Iterator.Element]] {
        var categories: [[Iterator.Element]] = []
        for element in self {
            let key = dateKey(element)
            guard let dayIndex = categories.index(where: { $0.contains(where: { Calendar.current.isDate(dateKey($0), inSameDayAs: key) }) }) else {
                guard let nextIndex = categories.index(where: { $0.contains(where: { dateKey($0).compare(key) == (ascending ? .orderedDescending : .orderedAscending) }) }) else {
                    categories.append([element])
                    continue
                }
                categories.insert([element], at: nextIndex)
                continue
            }

            guard let nextIndex = categories[dayIndex].index(where: { dateKey($0).compare(key) == (ascending ? .orderedDescending : .orderedAscending) }) else {
                categories[dayIndex].append(element)
                continue
            }
            categories[dayIndex].insert(element, at: nextIndex)
        }
        return categories
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
class Model {
    let date: Date!
    let anotherProperty: String!

    init(date: Date, _ anotherProperty: String) {
        self.date = date
        self.anotherProperty = anotherProperty
    }
}

let modelArray = [
    Model(date: Date(), anotherProperty: "Original Date"),
    Model(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(86400), anotherProperty: "+1 day"),
    Model(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(172800), anotherProperty: "+2 days"),
    Model(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(86401), anotherProperty: "+1 day & +1 second"),
    Model(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(172801), anotherProperty: "+2 days & +1 second"),
    Model(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(86400), anotherProperty: "+1 day"),
    Model(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(172800), anotherProperty: "+2 days")
]

let groupSorted = modelArray.groupSort(byDate: { $0.date })
print(groupSorted) // [["Original Date"], ["+1 day", "+1 day", "+1 day & +1 second"], ["+2 days", "+2 days", "+2 days & +1 second"]]

let groupSortedDesc = modelArray.groupSort(ascending: false, byDate: { $0.date })
print(groupSortedDesc) // [["+2 days & +1 second", "+2 days", "+2 days"], ["+1 day & +1 second", "+1 day", "+1 day"], ["Original Date"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified ElegyD's solution to handle optional date object

```
    fileprivate func compare(date:Date, to:Date, toGranularity:Calendar.Component)->ComparisonResult{
    return Calendar.current.compare(date, to: to, toGranularity: toGranularity)
}

    func groupSort(ascending: Bool = true, toGranularity:Calendar.Component, byDate dateKey: (Iterator.Element) -> Date?) -> [[Iterator.Element]] {
    var categories: [[Iterator.Element]] = []
    for element in self {
        guard let key = dateKey(element) else {
            continue
        }
        guard let dayIndex = categories.firstIndex(where: { $0.contains(where: {
            if let date = dateKey($0){
                return Calendar.current.isDate(date, inSameDayAs: key)
            }
            return false
        })
        }) else {
            guard let nextIndex = categories.firstIndex(where: {
                $0.contains(where: {
                    if let date = dateKey($0){
                        return self.compare(date: date, to: key, toGranularity: toGranularity) == (ascending ? .orderedDescending : .orderedAscending)
                    }
                    return false
                })
            }) else {
                categories.append([element])
                continue
            }
            categories.insert([element], at: nextIndex)
            continue
        }
        
        guard let nextIndex = categories[dayIndex].firstIndex(where: {
            if let date = dateKey($0){
                return self.compare(date: date, to: key, toGranularity: toGranularity) == (ascending ? .orderedDescending : .orderedAscending)
            }
            return false
        }) else {
            categories[dayIndex].append(element)
            continue
        }
        categories[dayIndex].insert(element, at: nextIndex)
    }
    return categories
}
```

USAGE
struct DataItem{
var date:Date?
}

let items = [DataItem(), DataItem(date:Date())]
let grouped = items.groupSort(toGranularity: .month, byDate: {$0.date })

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Article: Codable {
    let title, publishedDate, cleanURL: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title
        case publishedDate = "published_date"
        case cleanURL = "clean_url"
    }
}

 struct Section {
    let title:String
    var article:[Article]
}

 newsResponse.articles?.forEach({ article in
                    if !self.dataSource.contains(where: {$0.title == article.publishedDate}) {
                        self.dataSource.append(Section(title: article.publishedDate ?? "", article: [article]))
                    } else {
                        guard let index = self.dataSource.firstIndex(where: { $0.title == article.publishedDate}) else { return }
                        self.dataSource[index].article.append(article)
                    }
                })
```

Comment: here we take object and check if date already contains on dataSource. if contains then we find existing array object of dataSource and append new date object other wise we append new section object.

Answer (score 0):

Since the date can be converted to a number, we can group objects using not only DateComponents, but also apply custom ranges using regular int and dictionary group

```
 // multiplier = seconds * minutes * hours * days...etc
 let groupedObjects = Dictionary(grouping: array) { (currentDate) -> Int in
            return Int(currentDate.date.timeIntervalSince1970) / multiplier
 }
 let correctDateObjects = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: groupedMarkers.map { (key, value) in
            return (key*multiplier, value)
 })
```

Remember to convert the Int type to Date if you need it